# how to prove that the pre-order tree traversal algorithm terminates?

Tags: algorithm

I see **structural induction** the usual way for proving an algorithm's **termination** property, but it's not that easy to prove by means of induction on a **tree** algorithm. Now I am struggling on proving that the pre-order tree traversal algorithm is terminable:

```
preorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  visit(node)
  preorder(node.left) 
  preorder(node.right)
```

How should I prove?

Comment: Hint: induction on the height.

Comment: @Haile it's not a homework. actually, my question is based on a graph that may contain cycles. this is a simpler version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [strong induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction) on the height of the tree.

### Base case

**The algorithm terminates on a tree of height 0**, since in a tree of height 0 we have the root with no son. `visit(node)` on the root is a single step, visit on `node.left` and `node.right` terminate since they're both `NULL`.

### Inductive Step

**Suppose that pre-order traversal terminates on all trees of height `0, 1, 2, .. n`, we prove that it terminates on all trees of height `n+1`.** Let's look at it:

```
visit(node)
```

terminates since it's a single step.

```
preorder(node.left)
```

terminates since if our tree has height `n+1` then `node.left` is a tree of height at most `n`, and by strong inductive hypothesis pre-order traversal terminates on a tree of height less or equal than `n`.

```
preorder(node.right)
```

the same as `node.left`.

Answer (score 1):

Tree doesn't contain cycle. If there were cycles the algorithm will run forever. Hence absence of cycle is a key point to the proof. Other point is left or right are bound by memory constraints to point to null eventually.

Comment: If there are cycles, we have a graph and the algorithm may end by changing the if test to include a verification on whether the node was already visited.

Comment: @rlinden but the set of all graphs is not countable. i am not sure whether the set of all graphs is well-found. if not, we even can not use induction to prove.

Comment: I don't think that your consideration changes the algorithm, for it applies on a single graph that is represented in memory and, hence, is finite.